# How to apply Instafeed in cubeportfolio?

Tags: jquery, html, instafeedjs

I've this problem for several days, but I don't know what to do. So I tried to add image from instafeed instead put static in HTML or getting data from database, because I want the picture is the same with the instagram profile.

This is what I've tried so far

```
/*-------------------------------------------------*/
/* =  Instafeed
/*-------------------------------------------------*/    
try {
    var userFeed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: settings.userId,
        clientId: settings.clientId,
        accessToken: settings.accessToken,
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        limit: 8,
        template: '<div class="cbp-item ig"><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" class="cbp-caption"><div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="https:{{image}}" alt="{{image}}"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><div class="cbp-l-caption-title">{{location}}</div><div class="cbp-l-caption-desc">{{caption}}</div></div></div></div></a></div>',
    });
    userFeed.run();
} catch(err) {

}
```

Above is the code of instafeed and I already make the `template` is from the cubeportfolio. and below is the cubeportfolio js.

```
// PortfolioGrid
$('#js-grid').cubeportfolio({
    filters: '#js-filters',
    layoutMode: 'grid',
    sortToPreventGaps: true,
    mediaQueries: [{
        width: 1500,
        cols: 3
    }, {
        width: 1100,
        cols: 3
    }, {
        width: 800,
        cols: 3
    }, {
        width: 480,
        cols: 2
    }, {
        width: 320,
        cols: 1
    }],
    defaultFilter: '*',
    animationType: 'sequentially',
    gapHorizontal: 15,
    gapVertical: 15,
    caption: 'zoom',
    displayType: 'sequentially',
    displayTypeSpeed: 100
});
```

It does appear on the website `but only` in `inspect element` but the image is there. Here is the code on inspect element

[image]

As you can see it does appear but the problem is cubeportfolio adding style to those items like this (If I put directly on the HTML files it does appear). Below is the image from inspect element, as you can see the first item has style on it, and it's dynamically added by cubeportfolio.

[image]

So how to make those items from the instafeed got style from the cubeportfolio? I already tried put the cubeportfolio in the instafeed js, so when instafeed finish, then it'll start cubeportfolio, but it still doesn't working.

I appreciate any kind of helps, thank you

EDITED:

Even after I tried to run cubeportfolio after instafeed, it still doesn't working

```
function cubePortfolioFunc() {
    $('#js-grid').cubeportfolio({
        filters: '#js-filters',
        layoutMode: 'grid',
        sortToPreventGaps: true,
        mediaQueries: [{
            width: 1500,
            cols: 3
        }, {
            width: 1100,
            cols: 3
        }, {
            width: 800,
            cols: 3
        }, {
            width: 480,
            cols: 2
        }, {
            width: 320,
            cols: 1
        }],
        defaultFilter: '*',
        animationType: 'sequentially',
        gapHorizontal: 15,
        gapVertical: 15,
        caption: 'zoom',
        displayType: 'sequentially',
        displayTypeSpeed: 100
    }); 
} 

function instaFeedFunc(callback) {
    try {
        var userFeed = new Instafeed({
            get: 'user',
            userId: settings.userId,
            clientId: settings.clientId,
            accessToken: settings.accessToken,
            resolution: 'standard_resolution',
            limit: 8,
            template: '<div class="cbp-item ig"><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" class="cbp-caption"><div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="https:{{image}}" alt="{{image}}"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><div class="cbp-l-caption-title">{{location}}</div><div class="cbp-l-caption-desc">{{caption}}</div></div></div></div></a></div>',
        });
        userFeed.run();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
}

(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    instaFeedFunc(cubePortfolioFunc());
}(jQuery));
```

EDITED:

```
<!-- Portfolio -->
<section class="p0">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">    
            <div class="portfolio-no-gutter-fullwidth cbp" id="js-grid"></div>           
        </div>
    </div>
</section>            
<!-- End Portfolio -->
```

Comment: try to initialize  cubeportfolio in `after` function of instafeed

Comment: @Nidhi I already tried it but cubeportfolio still didn't give the style

Comment: @Nidhi please check the edit, Thank you

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to intialize  cubeportfolio in after function of Instafeed like below:
**Edit:** added my code please compare it with your code with your client id and access token it's working for me in my system

```js
var userFeed = new Instafeed({
    get: 'user',
    tagName: 'instafeed',
    userId: settings.userId,
    clientId: settings.clientId,
    accessToken: settings.accessToken,
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    limit: 8,
    template: '<div class="cbp-item ig"><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" class="cbp-caption"><div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap"><img src="https:{{image}}" alt="{{image}}"></div><div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap"><div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter"><div class="cbp-l-caption-body"><div class="cbp-l-caption-title">{{location}}</div><div class="cbp-l-caption-desc">{{caption}}</div></div></div></div></a></div>',
    after: function () {
        // PortfolioGrid
        $('#instafeed').cubeportfolio({
            filters: '#instafeed',
            layoutMode: 'grid',
            sortToPreventGaps: true,
            mediaQueries: [{
                width: 1500,
                cols: 3
            }, {
                width: 1100,
                cols: 3
            }, {
                width: 800,
                cols: 3
            }, {
                width: 480,
                cols: 2
            }, {
                width: 320,
                cols: 1
            }],
            defaultFilter: '*',
            animationType: 'sequentially',
            gapHorizontal: 15,
            gapVertical: 15,
            caption: 'zoom',
            displayType: 'sequentially',
            displayTypeSpeed: 100
        });
    }
});
userFeed.run();
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="cubeportfolio.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./instafeed.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://scriptpie.com/cubeportfolio/live-preview/cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.min.js"></script>
    
<!-- Portfolio -->
    <section class="p0">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="portfolio-no-gutter-fullwidth cbp" id="instafeed"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Portfolio -->
```

Comment: Now it doesn't show anything at all, in inspect element I can't see the items

Comment: can you add your html also because in the images you have provided I can't see any div with id `js-grid`

Comment: yeah sure, it's there now

Comment: I can't check from your snippet, but it does give the items a style?

Comment: WOW it's working, can you explain to me? what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Oh great. I think its problem with initializing of elements, instafeed library append its content to div which has id 'instafeed` and you dont have any div with that id so i cahnged id of the div with `js-grid` to `instafeed` and then initialize cubeportfolio on same div

Comment: Ahh I see, but my code it's appear but hidden because cubeportfolio didn't gave them any style. Why I didn't think about it. SO many thanks!!